# Create Bootstrap Front-end for Ruby on Rails application

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I was tasked to build a front end for a Ruby on Rails application and since I previously used bootstrap for my .net application I thought it would be cool to use it for that as well.

I have absolutely NO EXPERIENCE with RoR and I really don't have much time to complete this so I didn't want to start from scratch with learning rails so I thought I could just build the front end using bootstrap and then integrate that with the RoR app.

I did not build the RoR app, I am just being asked to build the front end.

Is there a way to just create the html with the same css and javascript and then add the Ruby application to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start be creating your basic template, the one of the bootstrap examples:

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples

Once you have your HTML mocked up and looking how you should, you should then be be able to start to fill values in to the page <%= value %>

Comment: would you be able to point me to an example doing this with page values? Kind of confused at how to tackle this.

Comment: take a look at this example:
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout
I must admit i'm not much of a Ruby guy, however it is very similar to the way you would render values in MVC or ASP <% %>

Comment: Some more basic examples in this basic github project:
https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-bootstrap/blob/master/app/views/layouts/_navigation.html.erb

you can take a look at the layouts folder to see some of these

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Ruby gem for Twitter Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) that you can add to your asset pipeline (the aspect of the RoR architecture that combines & minifies your assets like CSS & JS). Then you can just write Bootstrap-conformant HTML in the Rails views and the styles will be applied.

But if I'm understanding your last question correctly, there's no way to write a front-end and hook Rails up to it as a back end. The two are integrated in the Rails ecosystem.

Comment: That's not strictly true; it is possibly to write a backend-agnostic app in Backbone or Ember or another JS framework. However, in most cases, you are correct.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right about the JavaScript frameworks.